# Typescript inference type from columns data object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object which describe my table, in object I have `dataFields` - array of data, which has 3 keys - `name` - required string, `label` - required string and `field` - not required string. So I want another props - `test` in root object which will one of value of `field` or value of `name` in case if `field` not exists. What type of `test` must be ?

```
type FieldType<Name extends string, Field extends string> = {
  name: Name;
  label?: string;
  field?: Field;
}


type ComponentProps<Name extends string, Field extends string> = {
  dataFields: FieldType<Name, Field>[],
  test?: Field | Name; // what type ?
  // test?: Field extends string ? Field : Name; // it's not correct
}

const component = <Name extends string, Field extends string>(props: ComponentProps<Name, Field>) => {}


component({
  dataFields: [
    { name: 'surname', label: 'FIELD1', field: 'my_surname' },
    { name: 'name', label: 'FIELD2', field: 'my_name' },
    { name: 'patronymic', label: 'FIELD3' },
  ],
  test: 'surname' // must be 'my_surname' | 'my_name' | 'patronymic' not 'surname' or 'name'
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4&ssl=11&ssc=69&pln=11&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrggHgHIEMC20EAHsBAHbIDOUVwATnOQOYA0sCKUJZlNdjFgD4oAXigBvAFBQo5AhABcUPIQDcMqIlwAjJAH5lApsw2yAZp2SGOSZBoC+U56EhQAwgHt8YT+QrAAAr0nmBUOArcpBTUtAwm7PB2UbyxxsJikprIuMC4SShUygVoGBGEiVZCANoAuqyaZHQ2JVAAPioKalAA9D1QAO4AFrlQrtD6mn1jEM3FVikx-PEsUPq2XMqqEN3TcMAA5DTknsBQAMae9PQQ58BSTlKX5HQX3r7+5Gfi5UTRfHFBGwNshFgD0swhAAKMAhMLKLw+PwBYKhcLbSp2IQASjEIgkjye72RXyh0lkOTyJSKUGqmlkEjkCmURwArvR5IQDuxtHpECyYABJACiABkACIARm5UEsdhZ+BAAH0qOzORADlAHA1ZAymYQWeqZbykAKRRKAEwyuUoBXKo1anW6xnqllgXIhcggfBwc7G3SmqAHIVi8UAZk12s09Uas2ALNVHIUmum+FZrz0QcVKrVyfaWfteY6B3dDD83t9mpOZzZSa5UCuQaND2xUiAA)

try to inference `test` by infer with FieldType<Name, Field>, but no result

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqqlrm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, It's correct what I need ! Can you explain why in ComponentProps 1 generic, not 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `ComponentProps` is that the two [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters `Name` and `Field` will be inferred as two separate [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types corresponding to the set of `name` and `field` properties.  But then you lose the *correlation* between them.  If `Name` is `"surname" | "name" | "patronymic"` and `Field` is `"my_surname" | "my_name"`, we've lost the information about which member of `Name` goes with which member of `Field` and, crucially, which members of `Name` don't go with any member of `Field`.

One approach to fix this is to use a single generic type parameter `T` corresponding to the union of `FieldType` objects that appear as elements of the `dataFields` array.  So each member of the `T` union will have a pair of `name`/`field` properties (or just a `name` property), and we can iterate over those to compute the type of `test`.  It could look like this:

```
type ComponentProps<T extends FieldType<string, string>> = {
  dataFields: readonly T[],
  test?: T extends { field: infer F extends string } ? F : T["name"]
}
```

The type of `test` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) that splits `T` into its union members, then checks each one to see if it has a `string`-valued `field` property.  For each member with such a property, we use its type.  Otherwise we use the type of the `name` property.

Then `component` can be written as

```
const component = <const T extends FieldType<string, string>>(
  props: ComponentProps<T>) => { }
```

The changes I've made are to give `component()`'s `T` type parameter a [`const` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to encourage the compiler to infer [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for the `name` and `field` properties instead of just the correct-but-useless `string` type.  And since `const` modifiers tend to infer [`readonly` array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) types, I've changed `ComponentProps` to accept `readonly T[]` instead of just `T[]`.

Okay, let's test it:

```
component({
  dataFields: [
    { name: 'surname', label: 'FIELD1', field: 'my_surname' },
    { name: 'name', label: 'FIELD2', field: 'my_name' },
    { name: 'patronymic', label: 'FIELD3' },
  ],
  test: 'surname' // error!
  // Type '"surname"' is not assignable to type 
  //'"my_surname" | "my_name" | "patronymic" | undefined'.
})
```

Looks good.  The type of `test` is inferred as `"my_surname" | "my_name" | "patronymic" | undefined` (the `undefined` comes in because `test` is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)), as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrggHgHIEMC20EAHsBAHbIDOUVwATnOQOYA0sCKUJZlNdjFgD4oAXigBvAFBQo5AhABcUPIQDcMqIlwAjJAH5lApsw2yAZp2SGOSZBoC+U56EhQAwgHt8YT+QrAAAr0nmBUmKjcpBTUtijokJjGLOzJzEIi4tKyyLjAuPB2VMr0ELjIfoggUKgA2gC6rJpkdDaRPDE0ElCWdspM5hD0sFG8sWlQDlD6I8p1AETyhPP1Uk5SAMZ+dFBbPn4BYlCYW+Q77dF8cWgYSQwmqffCQgAUmmAhYcpe+-7kQZ9wqghABKMQibrrTbeXx-YAvbJQXL5QooYpQWqaWTdJZKKAAcioAFd6Lj8extHpEMp8TAAJIAUQAMgARACM5J6Vhp+BAAH1iaSFPjJk1ZNi5AoaWSKbokDT6cyWQAmTm9FA8-lk0VYySSwg0sB5ELkED4OAbTmU+UExWsgDMIocYqgjWaEDoNMF2oA9D7uPQQvQAISaP01DAE+behTzEVwGjkTzAKC4KhUODMeQ6RDQYCeKCuaBhn34+a8gUk3HzKAAHyg5a1sbrDaNDD8ZotNfrRMoEEs-mQ+IAdGsQVIgA)

Comment: Thank's a lot ! Really usefull information and explaination